# Show/Hide TabBarController in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

i am making an application in iphone in which i have 4 tabbars & in one of its tab i have 4 views in 2nd view it needs to hide the tab bar. I am able to hide the tab bar using the setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:YES in in the initWithNib method of the Viewcontroller being pushed. But when navigating to the screen 3 , calling the same method with "NO" does not make the tab bar appear. any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

John Smith is correct. The URL for that sample is: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/TheElements/index.html

The code that does this is in AtomicElementViewController.m, and the line that achieves this effect is in the init method:

```
    self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
```

Comment: where is the code to bring the tab bar controller to visible?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue to show or hide tab bar controller with UITableViewController customized class. Somehow, by using the following codes, does not work to hide tab bar controller:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
     self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;

}
```

In the case of storyboard with segue, initWithStyle: method does not get called.

Instead, I have to overwrite the property to make it work:

```
- (BOOL) hidesBottomBarWhenPushed {
  return YES;
}
```

My case is for iOS 5.1 with storyboard and segue to push to the next view (where I want to hide tab bar controller).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Apple's Elements projects. They hide and unhide the tab-bar  when you view and individual element.

Answer (score 1):

Before you push your 3rd view onto the stack, set the 2nd view's hidesBottomBarWhenPushed to NO.