# Removing the tab bar

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

In most part of my iPhone application I want to show things with navigation controller and tab bar.
But for few screens I need more space so I want to remove the tab bar.

I found before calling the controller that doesn’t need the tab bar I can set to hide it,

```
CardImageViewController *cardImage = [[CardImageViewController alloc] 
initWithNibName:@"CardImageViewController" bundle:nil];

cardImage.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:cardImage animated:YES];
[cardImage release];
```

The problem is now I can’t get it to display again. If I set

```
xxx.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = NO;
```

for the next controller still I can’t see the tab bar

How do I get it to display.

Comment: This answer to a similar question appears to do the trick: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356828/show-hide-tabbarcontroller-in-iphone/2025749#2025749

Answer (score 0):

The bar will remain hidden until you pop that controller that you hide off the navigation stack.

Refer to: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

One way to solve this is to present modal view for those controllers that you want to hide the tab bar

Answer (score 0):

In which view you want tab Bar hide use

cardImage.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;

this before push

and now in viewWillDisAppear of same view you need

cardImage.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = NO;

Comment: This work very well for a one-view controller.

In my case several views that I need to hide more than 1 tab bar

(1st view – tab bar),

(2nd view – no tab bar),

(3rd view – no tab bar),

(4th view – tab bar),     

is there a way to skip multiple views

Comment: If I used the navigation controller back button to go back, then tab bar will gain appear in the 2nd view controller, which we hide before